# Spotlight constantly indexes MacBook Air (Lion). Takes up 50+% of cpu

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, spotlight, activity-monitor

So I noticed my Air was running very slow. Opened Activity monitor and noticed a process `mdworker` taking up most of the space. I googled it and it seems to be related to Spotlight.

I opened Spotlight and there appears to be a progress bar along with the message that it is indexing my MacBook Air. I've let this run for ages now but it seems to be stuck at 95%. I tried restarting but I get the same thing. Force quitting `mdworker` does nothing as it just seems to start again.

Would anyone have any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to erase the Spotlight index by either running `sudo mdutil -Ea` or by temporarily adding your startup disk to the privacy tab in the Spotlight preference pane.

If that doesn't work, try to run:

```
sudo lsof|grep mdworker
```

or

```
sudo mdutil -Ea;opensnoop -n mdworker
```

to see if the indexing hangs on some specific files.